# Web scraping golf data from ESPN. I am receiving 3 ouputs of the same table and only want 1. How can I limit this?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and am stuck. I cant figure out how to only output one of the tables given. In the output, it gives the desired table, but three versions of them. The first two are awfully formatted, and the last table is the table desired.

I have tried running a for loop and counting to only print the third table.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard'

dfs = pd.read_html(url, header = 0)

for df in dfs:
    print(df[0:])
```

Comment: Hey, try using the code block function in the editor, makes code look nicer. You can also just indent all your code with 4 spaces for same effect. I'll update it for you now.

Comment: The site developer has used tables as layout so there are actually 3 tables in the source. As the answer says below just grab the 3rd one, looks to be what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use index to print the table.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard'

dfs = pd.read_html(url, header = 0)
print(dfs[2])
```

OR

```
 print(dfs[-1])
```

OR If you want to use loop then try that.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard'

dfs = pd.read_html(url, header = 0)
for df in range(len(dfs)):
    if df==2:
        print(dfs[df])
```